# Password for specific database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here on my company we have a SQL Database with several users. However everyone knows the password of 'sa' user.

Now, we have create a Intranet and it is necessary to limit the access to the Intranet database.

I have tryed to create a new owner and remove the permissions from 'sa' user to this database but with no success. What it is more recommended?

Continue this or create a new password for this specific database (is this possible)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change the sa password.

Comment: 1st change the password. Then, give it only to the people that manage the DB ( backups, creating SP and so on). For every other user that use the database to SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE records from DB create users, and give them specific permission. 2nd you can't remove the rights or delete the "sa" user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply suggest reset the SA account's password. Very very few people should know this password ever. If you need to give specific people this access, then create accounts for them. Applications should almost never have this level of access.

Edit: In MS Sql Server you can have a user on the server level with no access, and then you make that user DBO in a specific database - this enables a user to "admin" a database without being able to mess with the server settings.. This is highly recommended imho.

Here is a detailled guide on how to do it:

First make a login:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

Then give that user access to the DB:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx

Comment: Ok, I will change it. But there is a way to add a new password for a specific database?

Comment: Yeah there is.. I'll add some text with explanation

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use SQL Server logins**

Use windows logins. When the user should not have access, remove the windows login. You can't make people forget a password but you can revoke windows login access.